# Changing editor in abcde

Tags: cd-ripping, abcde

I ran `abcde`, but wanted to edit the CD information.  When I said yes, it gave me a menu of editors to choose from.  I unintentionally selected `nano` as the editor.  I canceled `C-c`'d the process.  Now when I run `abcde` it automatically uses the `nano` editor, which is not what I want.

Where/how does `abcde` keep the editor choice selection?

Note: there is no `~/.abcde.conf` in my home directory.  The system wide `/etc/abcde.conf` does not include information on the editor choice.  I can't figure out how the selection I made during one run is getting to my current attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acbde` uses your default text editor by reading the shell variable `$EDITOR`.

By default, the preferred text editor is `nano` on Ubuntu. If you want something else, you can set the variable to a text editor of your choice by appending a line such as

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

to the file `~/.bashrc`. Replace `vim` with the editor of your choice, of course. Remember to re-source your `.bashrc` after you edited it by running `. ~/.bashrc` before you run `abcde`, or simply log out and back in.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, `abcde` uses the wrapper `/usr/bin/sensible-editor`.
To show the selection again, run `select-editor` or delete `~/.selected_editor`.